# CDF for a random variable that is neither discrete nor continuous

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We flip a fair coin. Then, if the result is tails, we stop.  If it is heads, 
we flip a second time and then stop. Let $X$ be the number of heads from the flip(s). If $X = 0$, let $Y = 0$. If $X = 1$ or $X = 2$, choose $Y$ uniformly at random from the interval $[0,X]$.

How can I find the c.d.f. of $Y$? I know that $P(X = 0) = 1/2$, $P(X = 1) = 1/4$, and $P(X = 2) = 1/4$. But, how can I extend this information to get the c.d.f. of $Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $y$, we need to find $\Pr(Y\le y)$. It is clear that $\Pr(Y\le y)=0$ if $y\lt 0$, and $\Pr(Y\le y)=1$ if $y\gt 2$. Now we look at the interesting part, where $0\le y\le 2$.

Note that if $y=0$, then $\Pr(Y\le y)=\frac{1}{2}$. Now let $0\lt y\le 1$. Then we can have $Y\le y$ in three ways: (i) We got a tail; (ii) We got a head and a tail; (iii) We got two heads.

(i) gives a contribution of $\frac{1}{2}$. For (ii), given that we got one head, we have $\Pr(Y\le y)=y$. This gives a contribution of $\frac{1}{4}y$. For (iii), given that we got two heads, $\Pr(Y\le y)=\frac{y}{2}$. This gives a contribution of $\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{y}{2}$.

Thus if $0\lt y\lt 1$ we have $\Pr(Y\le y)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{y}{4}+\frac{y}{8}$.

We leave it to you to deal with $1\lt y\le 2$.